# Codeigniter on duplicate key update with auto increment in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, primary-key

How to insert on duplicate key update in MySQL with the primary key is an auto increment number ? So the unique key cannot be specified for a new record..

Comment: Try this one..

$sql = $this->db->insert_string('table', $data) . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field=value';
$this->db->query($sql);
$id = $this->db->insert_id();

Comment: I am confused what is the variable $id ? How can they MySQL knows duplicate key if I dont specify the old key in the $data ? The data may contain the data with both old and new keys

Comment: @PriskaAprilia You need to insert data, data base id(Primary Key) auto increment??is it??

Comment: so man... whats the point? show your table structure. show insert-query what u ve tried and explain more clear what you want to recieve

Answer (score 1):

ODKU works not only for PRIMARY keys, it works on all UNIQUE keys.
So u should just define another one unique key to catch your duplicates.

```
    ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE (
    `field1`
/*    
...
    ,`fieldN`
*/
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You must alter your database table. For example this would make the column `'ITEMS.itemid'` primary key and autoincrement:

```
ALTER TABLE ITEMS CHANGE itemid itemid INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Then, when you add new rows to the table you don't have to specify `itemid`; it would generate an auto incremented value, and you won't get the 'duplicate key' error on update.